# Can we install Shopify on localhost for development?

Tags: shopify

Can we install shopify on localhost for development ?
like: we download opencart and can install on localhost for development.

IS there any way for shopify ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, you can't download "anything" from Shopify core like you would do with OpenCart. Shopify is a fully hosted SAAS solution.

Answer (score 5):

Yes. Sign up as a partner. You can then create as many test shops as you wish. A test shop is fully enabled with all the possibilities of Shopify. You can test out front-end code. You can write and install Apps for backend manipulations. And you can run all your Apps on localhost, connecting to your shop. As well, your theme can be localhost too with a file watcher keeping you sync'd to your dev shop.

Comment: Can we Download core files of  Shopify for modifications?

Comment: Of course not. Shopify is a hosted platform. That is like asking if you can download the core files of Amazon or Google. Not going to happen.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Shopify Theme Kit](https://shopify.github.io/themekit/) to download your app to a local work station and perform live updates from your local station